# Approx 1948 Brasil Brazil Airliner...what is it? Taildragger?

Tags: airliner, aircraft-identification

[image]

What plane is this? It's a taildragger, 4 blade prop, twin engine plane. The photo was taken approximately in 1948, maybe in Brazil?

Comment: "Flota ... cante" was enough to confirm Argentinian [FAMA](https://books.google.com/books?id=_xw5b_m-LzoC&pg=PA230&lpg=PA230&dq=airline+flota+1940s). So not Brazilian, Argentinian. That at least narrows down what it is and when, even if not all the way to a single type.

Comment: What is the lump on the top? Satellite internet?

Comment: @Harper Are you sure it's not a cocktail shaker?

Comment: @Harper It's a streamlined housing for a loop antenna, almost certainly for [radio direction finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_direction_finder#Operation).

Comment: Looks like the prop rotates the  "wrong" way.  ( ccw as viewed from behind )

Comment: @quiet flyer nice observation!

Comment: Maybe not uncommon for non-US aircraft?  But it did catch my eye.

Answer (score 27):

The airliner in the picture is a Vickers VC.1 Viking, registration LV-AFI, of the former Argentinian operator Flota Aérea Mercante Argentina.

According to [this source](http://loudandclearisnotenought.blogspot.com/2010/03/blog-post.html?m=1), the plane served the 
Secretaría de Aeronáutica under registration LV-XFJ for less than a month, from 10.9.1947 till 4.10.1947 before transferring to FAMA.

After FAMA, the plane in question served Fuerza Aérea Argentina from 4.5.1949 till 11.11.1951 under registrations T-80 and T-50.

[Wikipedia: Vickers VC.1 Viking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickers_VC.1_Viking)

[Wikipedia: Flota Aérea Mercante Argentina](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flota_A%C3%A9rea_Mercante_Argentina) (in Spanish)

Comment: How did you determine the registration number from this photograph?

Comment: @Jacob Krall under the wing, between the guy in all-whites and the one with white shirt and dark pants, you can see *FI*. To left of that, between two guys dressed in white, you can see the sharp bottom of a *V*. LV-AFI is the only VC.1 in FAMA fleet with a reg ending in *FI*. Registrations of Argentinian VC.1's were painted on the exact location shown in the picture, so there's pretty much zero chance of making a mistake.